Limit on-premise end-user access to Azure private VNET
I have the following scenario: How to allow user access only to the VNET that contains Application 1 and restrict access to the VNET that contains Application 2. The user is authenticated through an On-Premise Active Directory synchronized with EntraID. I was thinking about managing access at the WAF level or something similar. All users are from the same IP range. I have not found a way to set this up, any ideas?


Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Options:

If your firewall is integrated with user authentication (SSO, AD): add a rule to permit a user (group), deny all others.
If your network supports dynamic DNS for workstations: create a group with permitted hosts, add the desired host names and permit access for that group.
None of the above: create a DHCP reservation for the workstation in question, add a firewall rule to permit that permanent IP address. You might want to add strict DHCP snooping to your network to avoid anyone else hijacking that adress.

You have not provided a reasonable amount of information on your network so we can't offer specific advice.

Hello Zac67, all options 1, 2 and 3 are related to on-premise network configuration? In Azure, I assume native components. The on-premise IP addresses are dynamically assigned. I will explore all Azure Firewall options.

Yes, all options control access from the On-Premise network. On the Azure firewall you could open access that way (with option 3 either firewall could be used).
